# What is the Esperanto word for "intermediate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

It is common to see people describe themselves as *komencanto*, but what word is used to describe a person who is at the intermediate level? The Wells dictionary lists three words for intermediate: *meza*, *daŭriga*, *intera*. Are any of these words applicable?

What is the intermediate version of *Mi estas komencanto*?

Answer (score 11):

You can say *meznivelulo* or *progresanto*.

***Progresanto*** is the common term. The literal meaning is "one who is progressing" - but it's understood to be an intermediate speaker. *Meznivela* is a pretty common word for middle-level, but *meznivelulo* isn't all that common.

Comment: Thanks, Tomaso. It's little things like this that can be tricky about Esperanto. I probably wouldn't have come up with "Progresanto" alone, but if this is the word most commonly understood to mean intermediate speaker, that's certainly what I will use. Meznivelulo, when broken down, makes more sense to me though.

Comment: Me too - but try searching for the terms with Google. You get hundreds of hits for *meznivelulo* and thousands for *progresanto.*

Comment: *Komencanto* and then *progresanto*, those are the two levels I've heard of. Sometime further on one may become *flua parolanto* or  *spertulo*.

Answer (score 3):

The word I learned for this ***komencinto***, although it may not be in use as much as those noted by Tomaso.

I first saw the word used by Katalin Kovats in her website edukado.net. For example, it's used a couple of times on the page describing her Ekparolu project: http://edukado.net/ekparolu/projekto

It only has two hits in the Tekstaro. One from *Artikoloj el Monato* and the other from *La Ondo de Esperanto*.

You can see its intended meaning well in the hit from *La Ondo*:

> En OkSEJT-43 estis tri niveloj de instruado: por startuloj (gvidis
>   Blazio Vaha el Hungario), **komencintoj** (gvidis Oksana Burkina el
>   Peterburgo) kaj parolantoj/progresantoj (la lastaj ĉefe ludis lingvajn
>   ludojn kaj simile etosumis, sed ja en Esperanto, ĉar tiun grupon
>   partoprenis tri eksterlandanoj).

Comment: Interesting observations. After I posted my own answer, I questioned whether it should be *progres**anto*** or *progres**into***. There are at least a few blog writers who speak out very clearly in favor of the latter, but the former appears to be more common. Given that *progresanto* (one who is clearly making progress but not done making progress) speaks to me more clearly, I left my answer as it was. Personally, I find *komenc-**into/-anto*** a strange distinction - is a beginner currently beginning, or someone who recently completed beginning - but I hesitate to disagree with Katalin here.

Answer (score 1):

This website has all the levels based on the The Common European Framework of Reference for Languages: http://www.edukado.net/komunumo/korespondaservo

- Komencanto (A1)
- Komencinto (A2-B1)
- Meznivelulo (B2)
- Progresanto (C1)
- Fluparolanto (C2)